# Al compilar o limpiar el código sale "Error CS0006 No se encontró el archivo de metadatos"

Tags: c#, asp.net

No entiendo porque todo estaba bien, pero luego me aparece un error.

[image: imagen 1]

[image: imagen 2]

El error es el siguiente:

- Gravedad: Error
- Código: CS0006
- Descripción: No se encontró el archivo de metadatos `C:\Users\mmendozn\Documents\APLICACION-WEB-FOROS\Puebas De Foros\SistemaWebForosSirve\CapaLogicaNegocio\bin\Debug\CapaLogicaNegocio.dll`
- Proyecto: CapaPresentacion
- Archivo: `C:\Users\mmendozn\Documents\APLICACION-WEB-FOROS\Puebas De Foros\SistemaWebForosSirve\CapaPresentacion\CSC`
- Línea: 1
- Estado suprimido: N/D

Comment: Lee [ask], el título es carente de sentido y solo poner capturas no ayuda

Comment: Para eso sirve Ctrl+z

Comment: solo compila nuevamente el proyecto que da como resultado esa dll

Comment: Me paso lo mismo, verifique en la ruta donde se encuentra la DLL y estaba en blanco. lo que realice fue una compilación de la Dll. con eso se me solucionó el problema

Comment: Como hiciste esa compilación? Como lo hago? Tengo el mismo error y no puedo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lleva el codigo del proyecto a una ruta mas corta, cuando esta excede un cierto largo aparecen este tipo de problemas.

Copialo en la carpeta `c:\Dev\SistemaWebForosSirve` o algo asi, pero que la ruta sea mas corta